# Any idea how to get to this url with scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

The URL is "https://sb-content.pa.caesarsonline.com/content-service/api/v1/q/time-band-event-list?".

I think it uses Cloudflare which is why I am having difficulty but I am not sure if that is the only issue.  I don't necessarily need a solution shown in Scrapy, I have played around with cfscrape and can't get it to get any response other than 403 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that this is cloudflare blocking automated requests.

```
<title>Access denied | sb-content.pa.caesarsonline.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
```

You can use the library "cloudscraper" to try and bypass this but as cloudflare changes their detection methods periodically you might eventually have troubles until the library is updated.

Cloud Scraper Library: https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/

**Example:**

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
response = scraper.get("https://sb-content.pa.caesarsonline.com/content-service/api/v1/q/time-band-event-list?").text
print(response)
```

**Output:**

```
{"data":{"timeBandEvents":[{"type":"LIVE","date":null,"competitionSummary":[],"events":[],"outrights":[]},{"type":"NEXT_TO_GO"........
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks man.  Not sure why I couldn't get cfscrape working properly

Comment: @weston6142 All good, I am glad it helped! Also if this did answer your question make sure to mark the answer as the correct one, it helps me out a little! Have a good one.